# What is this type of puzzle called?

Tags: puzzle-identification

for these puzzles you're given a set of letter pairings that you line up into a code via the overlapping letters as an example:

you have pairs "CA", "CO", "DC" and "OD" for a 5-letter code. with the answer being CODCA (contains CO, OD, DC, CA in that order)

Comment: Pattern matching?

Comment: Pattern matching would be a generic category of puzzle though sadly it's starting to look like this particular puzzle type doesn't have a proper name

Comment: An interesting term to look up for this puzzle is "Eulerian Path" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path

Comment: @LeppyR64 Quite true. Once you convert the letter pairs into the directed edges of a graph where the nodes are the letters, the puzzle becomes trivial.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Or it has a whole bunch of solutions :)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a $1$-dimensional [overlapping jigsaw puzzle](https://www.iwin.com/games/venn---overlapping-jigsaw-puzzle),

or [Marshall Squares](http://www.gottfriedville.net/puzzles/squares/squares.htm) in 1d.

They are very easy to make, just type in a string and then partition it accordingly.

For example:

> AD DF DS FD FS SA SF

is derived from:

> ADSFDFSA

To solve or check for the uniqueness of a solution, we can check all $k!$ permutations, but we can improve on this using a recursive sieved tree algorithm.

First check the opening pairs for successful candidates, and store the result in a new array as [{pair},last letter, remaining array], and repeat the process on the new array.

For example, the new array for my example, starting from:

```
[{},NULL,[AD,DF,FD,DS,SF,FS,SA]]
```

would contain:

```
[{AD,DF},F,[DS,FD,FS,SA,SF]]
...
[{FD,DF},F,[AD,DS,FS,SA,SF]]
[{FD,DS},S,[AD,DF,FS,SA,SF]]
...
```

giving only 13 new entries.

The next level should produce entries like:

```
[{AD,DF,FD},D,[DS,FS,SA,SF]]
```

and repeat until:

```
[{AD,DF,FD,DS,SF,FS,SA},NULL,[]]
```

for example.

(Note that this means my example is not uniquely defined - ADFDSFSA also works!)

Comment: Yea but I'm not looking to make them I'm looking for a proper name for them or a solver (which is what i was hoping to use the proper name for to see if anyone has written a solver)

Comment: Your example starts and ends on the same letter, which automatically allows multiple solutions by cyclically shifting parts, i,e. ADSFDFSA -> SADSFDFS -> FSADSFDF -> DFSADSFD -> FDFSADSF -> SFDFSADS -> DSFDFSAD.

Comment: That's interesting I'm not a programmer my self though I have done some script editing for some IRC bots back when i used to use mIRC and have written a number of .bat files back when I used to use Dos ... how would I go about using that method? (I also know how to use the browsers console(chrome) to some extent)

Comment: you need fairly sophisticated coding skills and a modern language, such as JavaScript, which will work in your browser. Try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ for a good reference site.